# Mongoose - Promise then() not triggered on save

Tags: express, mongoose, typescript2.0

I'm using ExpressJS + Mongoose + TypeScript. I have created a schema as below

```
const schema: Schema = new Schema({
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    gender: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    mobile: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    activationKey: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    isActivated: {
        type: Boolean,
        required: true
    },
    imagePath: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
});
```

I'm using the below code to save (insert) a new entry

```
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://MyUsername:MyPassword@ds135757.mlab.com:35777/my-db-us', (err, db) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('mongoose error: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('mongoose db: ' + db);

        const user = new User({
            firstName: 'ee',
            lastName: 'ee',
            email: 'eee@fff.com',
            gender: true,
            mobile: '333',
            password: '333',
            isActivated: true
        });

        user.save().then((someValue) => {
            console.log('saved');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('not saved:' + err);
        });
    }
});
```

**Console Messages**

*When correct data is sent. saved isn't printed*

```
mongoose db: [object Object]
```

*When incorrect data is sent*

```
mongoose db: [object Object]
not saved:ValidationError: gender: Path `gender` is required.
```

*When unable to connect to MongoDB if internet is disconnected*

```
mongoose error: MongoError: failed to connect to server [ds135777.mlab.com:35777] on first connect [MongoError: connection 0 to ds135777.mlab.com:35777 timed out]
```

**Module versions**

```
"mongodb": "^2.2.34",
"@types/mongodb": "^3.0.5",
"mongoose": "^5.0.4",
"@types/mongoose": "^5.0.2",
```

---

**Re-written example (Solution)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://MyUsername:MyPassword@ds135757.mlab.com:35777/my-db-us', function(err) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('err: ' + err);
    } else {
        console.log('connected');
        const user = new User({
            firstName: 'ee',
            lastName: 'ee',
            email: 'eee@fff.com',
            gender: true,
            mobile: '333',
            password: '333',
            isActivated: true
        });

        user.save().then((someValue) => {
            console.log('saved');
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log('not saved:' + err);
        });
    }
});
```

The messages printed are

```
connected
saved
```

Comment: Wow, this is really surprising.

Comment: Is the data getting saved in Mongodb or not?

Comment: @Sahil, I was able to reproduce the issue when the mongo connection fails. Can you change connection part to `mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhosts/test')
    .catch(() => {console.log("connect failed")});` and make sure there is no DB connection failure?

Comment: can you share your mongo connection code?

Comment: Added more details

Comment: @Sahil What version of Mongoose are you using?

Comment: @PhillipThomas: Added details

Comment: maybe because the `then` expects a function with one parameter and you're passing a function without parameter?

Comment: @ElmerDantas: Tried your suggestion. But same issue

Comment: Can you show your `MongoClient ` declaration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing a funny problem with your code(Just guessing looking at your variable name convention ;-)).

You are saying you use mongoose but you connect using native `MongoClient` (again guessing based on variable name) you must be connecting using mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

then just replace your `MongoClient` with `mongoose`

`then` doesn't print anything as nothing is happening there and `catch` prints error as validation happens before connection

Comment: Your suggestion (and as pointed by other users) was correct. I was connecting MongoClient and using Mongoose to save. I should have connected Mongoose and then saved.

This is working now. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The reason is you are using native client for connecting and using mongoose for modelling which is not the correct way. Do connect to the Mongo DB URI using mongoose and save schema.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a standard `MongoClient` connection, this will not effect mongoose models. The connection that created the `User` model must be `open` for the various database actions to work. Assuming that the `User` model was created using the global mongoose object (e.g. `mongoose.model('User', userSchema)`) then you must call `mongoose.connect()` to activate the model's connection. If the `User` model was created via a non-global connection (e.g. `mongoose.createConnection()`) then you should ensure that the connection is in the `open` state.